# Pourquoi peut-on utiliser « de par » dans certains cas ?

Tags: prépositions, constructions

Dans le film *Les visiteurs*, Jaqcouille a dit : « Je préfère mourir **de par** votre épée. »

Quelle est cette construction ?

Est-ce que ce « de par » pourrait remplacer « à cause de » dans une phrase plus banale, comme « Je suis fâché de par ça. » ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*De par* est une locution prépositionnelle qui a [plusieurs sens](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/par) (voir l'entrée « par³ (de) », ainsi que « [de](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de)¹ I.A.2 « Par ext. » »).

En français moderne, on la rencontre dans le sens de « du fait de », « à cause de », avec une nuance qu'il s'agit d'une cause intrinsèque, d'une condition nécessaire.

Un autre sens, vieilli, qui est probablement étymologiquement à l'origine du précédent, est « de la part de » au sens de « en vertu de l'autorité de ».

On trouve également cette préposition composée dans l'expression figée « de par le monde » qui signifie « quelque part dans le monde » avec la nuance que l'objet est dispersé ou qu'il faut chercher longtemps pour le trouver. Plus généralement, on peut appliquer *de par* à autre choses que le monde (« de par les campagnes », …), mais l'usage est littéraire sinon vieilli.

Le TLF donne l'étymologie de *de par* comme une altération de « de part » sous l'influence de la préposition *par*. Il n'est pas complètement clair que tous les sens de cette préposition aient la même étymologie. Le *Dictionnaire de l'ancienne langue française* de Godefroy ([p. 2:426, bas de la 3<sup>e</sup> colonne, *de* 3<sup>o</sup>](http://micmap.org/dicfro/previous/dictionnaire-godefroy/426/2/de)) cite « de par Dieu », « de par le roi » comme des « locutions toutes faites » déjà en ancien français.

« Mourir de par votre épée » ne peut pas du tout se dire en français moderne : on dirait « par votre épée ». Je ne trouve pas de référence qui confirmerait cette construction comme existant en ancien français, mais je ne suis pas expert en la matière. Il est tout à fait possible que la tournure ait été fabriquée pour le film. Un français contemporain comprend « par l'épée » et y voit une connotation vieillotte à cause des sens vieillis véritables de « de par ».

Answer (score 2):

« De par » est une expression désuète, altération de « de la part de ». Cela signifie « du fait de »,  « à cause de », « par la volonté de ».
On ne l'emploierait pas de nos jours, sauf pour produire un effet très particulier, mais il n'est pas étonnant de l'entendre dans un film qui se passe au Moyen-Âge. Ça fait « couleur locale » même si bien sûr le film ne reproduit pas le français parlé à l'époque.

Comment: Comment ecriveriez-vous la phrase que j'ai prise en exemple en Francais moderne ?

Comment: Désuet, il ne faut pas exagérer non plus… [Petit ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=de+par%2Cdu+fait+de&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3).

Comment: @oldergod: « je préfère mourir de votre épée »,  « Je préfère que ce soit votre épée qui m'envoie le coup mortel », « Je préfère que vous me plantiez un couteau dans le ventre. »

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Es-tu certain que le ngram tel que l'as programmé différencie la locution "de par" où "par" a le sens de "motif/raison"  (ex. du PO) et la juxtaposition des prépositions "de"+"par" ou "par" a son sens plus usuel de préposition de lieu et signifie "dans" ("je vais de par le monde") ?

Comment: « De par » existe en français moderne dans d'autres sens. Il existe sous forme vieillie pour signifier « de la part de », « en vertu de l'autorité de », mais ce n'est pas le sens ici. As-tu une référence qui justifierait l'emploi de « de par » en ancien français dans le sens qu'il a dans cette phrase ?

Comment: @Gilles Pour moi ici « de par » signifie « du fait de », « à cause de » et le dictionnaire historique de la langue française atteste ce sens dès le 12e siècle.